# Différence entre "genre" et "sorte"

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Quelle est la différence entre les mots "genre" et "sorte"? Est-ce que ce sont des synonymes ou est-ce qu'il y a des exemples où je ne peux qu'utiliser l'un ou l'autre? Merci d'avance!

Answer (score 4):

Genre et sorte sont utilisés de la même façon dans les expressions du type:

> Un [genre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/genre) de xxxx
>
> Une [sorte](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sorte) de xxxx

où ils signifient tous deux « une catégorie de xxxx », comme on aurait pu aussi utiliser « un type de… », « une espèce de… », « une variété de… » etc.

Certains de ces mots font partie d'une hiérarchie traditionnelle de classification du vivant, [les rangs taxonomiques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rang_taxonomique), du plus générique au plus spécifique :

> Règne/Embranchement/Classe/Ordre/Famille/Genre/Espèce/Variété/Forme

On dira donc:

> Le règne animal
>
> Le genre humain ou l'espèce humaine
>
> Une variété de chat

Dans la conversation courante ou lorsqu'on classifie des objets, on n'est bien sûr pas tenu de respecter cette hiérarchie.

*Sorte* et *type* ne font pas partie de cette liste et peuvent s'appliquer à tout élément de la hiérarchie du vivant.

> Un type/une sorte d'animal, de félin, de chat, de siamois…

Ces mots ne sont cependant pas toujours interchangeables. Ils peuvent avoir, dans un contexte particulier, un spectre d'utilisation bien précis, comme **genre** quand il s'agit de préciser masculin ou féminin.

> Accord en genre et en nombre
>
> Le genre féminin.

Dans d'autre cas, on ne peut pas modifier certaines expressions toute faites :

> De sorte que…    ←→    <s>De genre que</s>…
>
> Il y a toutes sortes de raisons qui… ←→    <s>Il y a tout genres de raisons qui</s>…

Comment: C'est donc l'usage, et l'usage seul, qui dicte lequel utiliser? Peut-être à préciser dans votre réponse.

Comment: @Frank Oui, l'usage dicte l'usage, une tautologie ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ils sont synonymes.

Un genre de ...

Une sorte de ...

Un type de ...

Un(e) espèce de ... (péjoratif)