# Le genre de fille

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

I was wondering if it would be possible to translate

> *she's not **the kind of girl** who spends hours in front of the mirror*

with

> *elle n'est pas **la fille** qui passe des heures devant le miroir*

or if it is absolutely necessary to use **le genre de fille** (*elle n'est pas le genre de fille qui...*)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not "absolutely necessary", but using it is more idiomatic.

Note that we'd rather say :

> ***Ce** n'est pas le genre de fille à passer des heures devant **son** miroir.*

or,

> *Ce n'est pas la fille qui passe des heures devant son miroir.*

and in spoken French:

> ***C'est** pas...*

Comment: It is more idiomatic, and so are a few synonyms like "le type de" or "la sorte de."

Comment: @spaghettibaguetti Oui, ça me rappelle une question: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24916/diff%c3%a9rence-entre-genre-et-sorte/24917#24917

Comment: Spontaneously, I would use a "futur simple" or even a "futur proche" with the auxiliary aller for this turn of phrase (and I would be unable to tell why or to relate it to a rule): *C'est pas le genre de fille qui passera/va passer des heures devant son miroir*.

Answer (score 1):

Most idiomatic, and pretty neutral in terms of formality:

> Elle n'est pas ***du genre à*** passer des heures devant un miroir.

Remove “*n'*” in casual spoken French.

In French, if the category (here “*fille*”) isn't really necessary, we tend to omit it. “*Être du genre à …*” is an almost word-for-word translation of “to be the sort who …”, and in French that's usually the most natural phrasing.

In informal, spoken French, you can also say “*être le genre à*” or even “*être genre à*”. I'd categorize it more as the omission of a word than an instance of some more general grammatical construct.

In informal French, you can start with “*C'est pas*”:

> C'est pas le genre à passer des heures devant un miroir.

(Or “*Ce n'est pas …*” which makes it less informal.) Here you can't use “*du genre à*” because that would make the pronoun *ce* look like it's referring to a thing, not a person. In “*C'est pas le genre à …*”, the pronoun *ce* can be thought of as referring to “*genre*”, which is not a person and therefore ok. The pronoun *ce* can refer to a person in the construct “*c'est*” (plural: “*ce sont*”), but there has to be something in the sentence that refers directly to a person. For example, this is possible (and without any awkwardness regarding *ce* referring to a person). It's not wrong, I just find it too wordy and would use “*du genre à*” as above instead.

> Ce n'est pas le genre de fille à passer des heures devant un miroir.

This is also possible, and a little formal, but again I find it a little too wordy:

> Elle n'est pas le genre de fille qui passe des heures devant un miroir.

Regarding the article in front of “*miroir*”, in French, it's a lot more natural to use an indefinite article, because it isn't referring to any specific mirror. If referring to the girl's routine, she presumably does it at home or with a portable mirror, so “*devant **son** miroir*” is also possible, but I find it less natural. It's also possible to consider “mirror” to be some kind of universal concept and use a definite article “*devant **le** miroir*”, but I find this definitely unnatural: it's more of a figure of speech than normal speech.